# Stop submitting the form on pressing enter key in Struts 2 + jQuery + json

Tags: jquery, json, forms, struts2

I have a from which loaded with data. Then I need to enter an ID in a text box and the system will fetch the details of that ID from the database. I have written an onChange event in jQuery to perform the action, which works perfectly. The onChange event works when we click out anywhere in the screen or when we press TAB key. If I press ENTER key once I finish the values, the form is getting submitted and the respective action method is triggered. I need to stop the form getting submitted. I have attached the required details. Please let me know the way to stop it.

Struts.xml

```
<action name="*Request" method="{1}"
        class="com.abc.actions.RequestsAction">
        <result name="save" type="json">
            <param name="root">messageBean</param>
        </result> </action>
```

JSP:

```
<s:form action="saveRequest.action" method="post" cssClass="form-horizontal" theme="simple" role="form">..
```

JS:

```
$("#saveRequest_requestBean_memberNumber").change(function(){
    alert('inside func');
    $(".alert-warning").hide();
    $(".alert-success").hide();......................
```

When I press enter, the save method in RequestAction class is called and the json response is displayed on the screen. I tried to bind the enter key (code=13) with the text field where I enter the value and tab out. Even then, the form is submitted. I tried all possible ways to stop the form being submitted. I also used preventDefault() method to stop propagating. FYI, **saveRequest_requestBean_memberNumber** is the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you tried preventDefault()? 
preventDefault is designated for your kind of purposes.

My suggestion :

```
$("#saveRequest_requestBean_memberNumber").change(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      // do something

});
```

Comment: I tried as you said, it did not work :( I even tried to bind the enter key with preventDefault() likewise. It did not work. $('#saveRequest_requestBean_memberNumber').keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
   $(this).trigger("enterKey");
  }
 });
  $('#saveRequest_requestBean_memberNumber').bind("enterKey", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();